# Сборка ядра linux EFI Stub

Tags: linux

Ядро Linux 3.2, компилирую ядро EFI Stub, монолитное, без initramfs, в стандартном пути  efi/boot/bootx64.efi. После перезапуска на экране висит только заставка. Произошла ли загрузка ядра - не понятно. Настройки для Linux EFI Stub взяты отсюда http://habrahabr.ru/post/165575/

Какие настройки можно произвести для того, чтобы ядро загружалось, или для того, чтобы понять, в каком оно состоянии?

Ранее уже было собрано ядро той же версии, и оно загружается с некоторыми ошибками, но работоспособное.

Answer (score 1):

Что первое на ум приходит - а BIOS там - UEFI или Legacy? В смысле, что если сборка под UEFI, то под старым БИОСом не загрузится никогда. Далее - если глючит видео, то можно через [Alt-F1] или [Ctrl-Alt-F1] войти в текстовый терминал, и в логах посмотреть, что там не так.Если же и это не получается, то значит реально не грузится ядро, и тогда вам сюда: http://wiki.opennet.ru/Linux_kernel_debug